# iOS - Does Apple Appstore support parallel distribution

Tags: ios, version-control, app-store

I wonder if there is any way to distribute different versions of same app (same means same bundle id, same account) in Apple Appstore.

Lets say, I want to distribute, MyApp (com.stackoverflow.myapp) version v1.2 but there is already a version v1.1 open to public. Is it possible to keep both version open for public. And fixing issues and release different sub version like, v1.1.2 and v1.2.2.

As far as I know with single bundle its not possible. But still I am curious if there is any workaround.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you release a new version on to the app store, you can now select an option for a "phased release", where the update is shown to current users incrementally over a 7 day period, but at the end of that seven day period the updated version is available to everyone.  Also, new users will get the latest release when they install from the App Store.

You cannot maintain two "active" releases on the store.

If you want to test a new version or new features with a limited set of users then TestFlight may be an appropriate tool.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the confirmation. I have another question. When I upload a latest version lets say v1.2, is it possible to upload IPA with older version e.g. v1.1.2 ?

Comment: No, all components in your version string must be "higher", so after 1.2.1 you can only release 1.2.2 1.2.3 etc or 1.3.1 1.3.2.  Once you have released 1.3.x you can't go back to a 1.2.x; the binary will be rejected during the upload.

Comment: What if I expire an older build? For example, sequence -> v1.1 -> v1.2 -> expire v1.2 -> is it possible to upload 1.1.2 now?

Comment: No, once you create a version, even if you never submit it, all newer versions must be higher.  Say you created 1.12 by mistake instead of 1.1.2, you would have to upload 1.13.1 or later next.

Comment: Thanks for clarifications

Answer (score 1):

You can use whatever versioning system you want (such as semantic versioning), but you can't distribute multiple versions of an app at a time without uploading them to the App Store as 2 entirely different apps